# Solving a System of Six unknowns using Six Equations

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations

As the title states, the problem seems fairly simple, but I'm having great difficulties with it. I am solving for a matrix which consists of three vectors made up of nine unknowns (we can cut it down to six using known symmetries). So, six unknowns, six equations that I have derived. Nothing too tricky. I'm going to name the unknowns: a, e, i, b, d, and c. The equations are as follows:

$a^2 + e^2 + i^2 = 29.1$
$b^2 + e^2 + d^2 = 29.1$
$c^2 + d^2 + i^2 = 156.25$
$(ae)+(be)+(di) = -14.55$
$(bd)+(cd)+(ei) = 0$
$(de)+(ai)+(ci) = 0$

That's literally it. I've spent a lot of time messing around with these equations but I've gotten nowhere, so maybe there's something that I'm missing. Any help at all would be appreciated.

edit: Additional background information. The matrix consists of (a1, a2, a3; b1, b2, b3; c1, c2, c3). Symmetries: a2=b1, a3=c1, b3=c2. The magnitude of vector a=5.394, b=5.394, c=12.5. Cos of vectors 12 = -.5. Cos of vectors 13, and 23 =0. This is the entirety of the information that I have to work with.

Comment: What's the origin of the problem? Cutting down to 6 variables might be a mistake; sometimes the expression in terms of the full set of unknowns is much easier to handle. As things stand there are certainly ways of studying the problem, but knowing the origin and how these equations were derived might give a much easier way of proceeding.

Comment: I am calculating the crystal lattice of a mineral in orthogonal space using only two pre-definied lattice constants. The problem with not utilizing the symmetries is that I have a very limited amount of information, and I certainly do not have anything close to nine equations. The equations that I do have were derived from the two lattice constants, basic vector magnitude equations, and trigonometric relationships that I know. I figured boiling it down to a straight up set of six equations with concrete numbers associated with each one would be the easiest way to go.

Comment: Are there any known restrictions on the variables? Are the values required to be real? nonnegative? positive? Do you just need a numerical solution (e.g., rounded values)?

Comment: It's obviously a lot of information, but can you put any of the details of that into the question?

Comment: The only restriction is that they need to be real. A few are expected to possibly be negative. There are also very likely some 0 values.

Comment: In fact, the varianle $i$ _must_ be zero.

Comment: What about "rounded" values? Or do you need exact symbolic values (e.g., radical expressions)?

Comment: Round values are completely fine. I updated the question with some more information

Comment: The variable $d$ must also be zero.

Comment: More info: 
$$c = \pm \frac{25}{2}$$
Also: $a=b$.

Comment: since this isn't a homework problem, why don't you just put it into mathematica or matlab?

Comment: I've actually tried and failed to do just that. I haven't used Matlab in a while and evidently I've very rusty

Comment: I'll post a complete symbolic answer shortly (it will take me a little while -- my typing skills are dismal and my MathJax knowledge is still novice level).

Comment: Much appreciated. You're a life-saver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Maple's Groebner basis package, I get the following result . . .

A $6$-tuple $(a,b,c,d,e,i)$ satisfies the system if and only if

\begin{align*}
&d = i = 0\\[6pt]
&c = {\small{\pm \frac{25}{2}}}\\[6pt]
&a = \pm \sqrt{{\small{\frac{291}{20}}}\left(1 \pm {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\sqrt{3}\right)}\\
&b = a\\[6pt]
&e = {\small{\frac{40}{291}}}a^3-4a
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much. I ran it in matlab and was only able to figure out d, i, and c. I have a way to check the rest of it though.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if we form the vectors $\vec{v}_1=\langle a, e, i\rangle$, $\vec{v}_2=\langle e, b, d\rangle$ and $\vec{v}_3=\langle i, d, c\rangle$ then the six written equations can be written as equations for the six dot products among these vectors (the three norms $|\vec{v}_i|^2$ and the three dot products $\vec{v}_i\cdot\vec{v}_j$ for $i\neq j$). In particular this means that the whole equation can be written as $\mathbf{M}^2=\mathbf{A}$ for the $3\times 3$ matrix $\mathbf{M}$ made up of the three vectors and a suitable constant symmetric matrix $\mathbf{A}$.

This can generally be solved by diagonalizing the matrix $\mathbf{A}$; if $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{P}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{P}^{-1}$ for diagonal $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{M}=\mathbf{P}\mathbf{M'}\mathbf{P}^{-1}$, then it's easy to see that $\mathbf{M'}^2=\mathbf{D}$, but this last equation can easily solved. The flexibility allowed by reflections (i.e., matrices $\mathbf{R}$ such that $\mathbf{R}^2=\mathbf{I}$) can then be used to try and force the equalities among coefficients that you're looking for.  (This is one reason to potentially work with the original set of variables, because it may be possible to write these scalar equality constraints in terms of more easily-solved vector constraints.) (**ETA**: And note that the 'original' version of the problem can be similarly specified in terms of computing a matrix square root of a symmetric matrix; this is a well-studied problem, and you should be able to find more information under that name.)

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm going to look into your last note there

Comment: [+1] Interesting explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You say you haven't had a full answer with Matlab.

In fact, it is possible to use Matlab to get all unknowns.

Here is the script (I have chosen to replace $i$ by $f$, in order to avoid problems with $i$ considered as a complex number):

```
  syms a b c d e f
  [a,b,c,d,e,f]=solve(a^2+e^2+f^2==29.1,...
      b^2+e^2+d^2==29.1,...
      c^2+d^2+f^2==156.25,...
      (a*e)+(b*e)+(d*f)==-14.55,...
      (b*d)+(c*d)+(e*f)==0,...
      (d*e)+(a*f)+(c*f)==0)
  simplify(a)
  simplify(b)
  simplify(c)
  simplify(d)
  simplify(e)
  simplify(f)
```

The answers are the same as @quasi has found but under the form:

- $a=b=\dfrac{1}{20}\left(\sqrt{1455}-3\sqrt{485}\right)$
- $c=\pm\dfrac{25}{2}$
- $d=f=0$
- $e=-\dfrac{1}{20}\left(\sqrt{1455}+3\sqrt{485}\right)$

A little remark: for $a$ there is a slight difference; numerical conversion shows that:

$a=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{291}{20}\left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}$

(no $\pm$ sign inside the square root).